# Is std::map<std::set<long>, double> AND std:map< std::pair<long, long>, double> a valid data type in C++?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I know that in `std::map` we have a key and a corresponding mapped value.

Now in the Data Type that i mentioned, key would be of type `std::set<long>`  or  `std::pair<long, long>` . So, is that valid keeping in mind that in map values are stored on the bases on sorted value of keys. So, is `std::map<std::set<long>, double>`  AND  `std:map< std::pair<long, long>, double>` valid ?

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing my dose of caffeine and my brain is out of order, but in your declaration `std::map<std::set, double>`, std::set is the template, not a type. You would have to write something like `std::map<std::set<int>, double>` to have a type.

Comment: Yes, i meant that only. But my laziness thought that part was self implied !

Comment: Apparently, Andre agrees with me, and I suspect your compiler would, too... Lazyness is a virtue, but don't abuse it... ;-)

Comment: @paercebal Got it ! :-) Would keep that in mind for future questions ! Thanks !

Comment: Again the syntax is wrong, the second template parameter should be a compare_function `std::map<std::set<long, std::less<long>, double >`. Are you trying to use a pair of long?

Comment: What is `std::set<long, long>`?

Comment: std::map< std::set<long, long> , double > MEANS KEY is of type std::set<long , long>  and the mapped value is of type double.

Comment: E.g.:  Suppose i have a std::set => (2,3). And suppose that the mapped value of this set is 0.1. So in this std::map,  (2,3) is MAPPED to 0.1.

Comment: What you want then is not `std::set<long, long>` but `std::pair<long, long>`, this will map a pair of longs to a double.

Comment: @andre : Hmmm... agree, std::pair would be more suitable. P.S.: But using std::set is still valid (though not the efficient way)! :-)

Comment: Well `std::set<long, long>` actually makes no sense. Have you tried to declare one and insert an element?

Comment: @user1599964: There is a significant difference between `std::set<long>` and `std::pair<long,long>` because the latter one is not a set but a pair where the order counts. So the pair (2,3) is actually different from the pair (3,2).

Comment: @ALL : Sorry for my wrong declaration. It caused a lot of confusions. I have edited the question again. I guess/hope now the question statement is correct !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) has an [`operator<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/operator_cmp) which performs a lexicographical comparison between two sets of the same type. So yes, an `std::set<T>` can be a valid key for a map.

An `std::pair<T1,T2>` also has an [`operator<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) implementing a lexicographical comparison, so `std::map<std::pair<T1, T2>, T3>` would also be valid *iff* both `T1` and `T2` have a less-than comparison `operator<` implementing strict weak ordering. So the requirements are tighter. Both `T1` and `T2` need the comparison to be keys of a map, but they do not need it to form a valid pair. So a valid pair does not necessarily form a valid key for a map. On the other hand, you can instantiate the map with your own comparison criteria.

```
std::map<std::pair<T1, T2>, T3, Comp> m;
```

Answer (score 4):

No, the syntax is wrong. What you want is `std::map<std::set<a_type_here>, double>`, so add the template parameter for set.

Note `a_type_here` should have `operator<` or you need to use `std::set<a_type_here, compare_function>`

**What you seem to want is:** `std::map<std::pair<long, long>, double> mapping`

**Example of how to use;** `mapping[std::make_pair(1,2)] = 0.1;`

Comment: If the type had no `operator<` then `set<T>` wouldn't even compile, so the question would be moot.